# ARCGIS - ST_GEOMETRY from ORACLE to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, oracle, esri

I have an ESRI Geodatabase stored on an Oracle System. This is where the data is generated and is considered the source system. I need to be able to run a job that extracts and imports the data into a SQL Server database (also leveraging ESRI sde). I know will have an issue with bringing the ST_Geometry type over to SQL Server but I have not been able to find any documentation as to what all is necessary to successfully preform this tasks. For example, what form should I extract the data from oracle? And what is required to import the feature. It is my understanding that the new row must be registered in various ways.

The datatype for Oracle Shape : `[SDE.ST_GEOMETRY]`

Datatype in SQL Server: `[Geometry]`

**UPDATE**

I have been able to successfully been able to convert the ST_Geometry from oracle into a varchar Well Known Text format. I did this by using the  `sde.ST_ASText()`. This required the configuration of external processes on oracle.

My select statement looks as follows:

`SELECT COL1, COL2, COL3, sde.ST_ASTEXT(SHAPE) AS SHAPE FROM TABLE`

Now the problem i am having is to convert this into a SQL SERVER GEOMETRY type. I am using a stored procedure that I would like to loop through the columns, append to a select statement and apply the `STGeomFromText()` function that is included in SQL SERVER.

I am unable to successfully do this.

Relevant code is as follows:

```
        SELECT COLUMN_NAME
        INTO #ColCursor
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE 
        WHERE TABLE_NAME = @TBL

        DECLARE
        @SEL varchar(MAX),
        @TCOL varchar(75),
        @GCOL varchar(75)

        SELECT @I = 0
        DECLARE ColCursor CURSOR FOR 
        SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM #ColCursor
        OPEN ColCursor
        FETCH ColCursor INTO @TCOL
        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0

        BEGIN
            IF @TCOL = 'SHAPE'
                BEGIN
                    SELECT @GCOL = 'STGeomFromText(@TCOL,@SRID)'
                END
            ELSE
                BEGIN
                    IF @I > 1 SELECT @SEL = @SEL + ', ' + @TCOL
                    ELSE SELECT @SEL = @TCOL
                    SELECT @I = @I + 1
                    FETCH ColCursor INTO @TCOL
                END
        END

        CLOSE ColCursor
        DEALLOCATE ColCursor

        SELECT @SEL = @SEL +', ' + @GCOL
```